# View a nick's idle time in /whois info on irssi

Tags: irc, irssi

On most IRC clients, doing `/whois` on a nick will display their idle time. However, irssi does not show this. Is there any way to make it show the idle time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This depends on the IRC *server*. Normally, the WHOIS query would be processed by the server you are on. But on IRC, servers only know idle time and away status for *directly connected* users. (This is to avoid *a lot* of unnecessary traffic between servers.)

To see idle time, put the nickname twice, [like this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-3.6.2):

```
/whois foo foo
```

This is aliased to /WII by default:

```
/wii foo
```

It is also in the builtin help:

```
/help whois
```

This will cause the query to be forwarded to the target user's server, which knows the idle time.

Note that on some networks, cross-server WHOIS queries can be heavily throttled (example: *freenode*).